# Ввод в TextBox значения по нажатию на Button

Tags: visual-studio

Здравствуйте, прошу помощи.

На форме имеется два компонента TextBox1 и Button. В TextBox1 я ввожу число и по нажатию на Button он должен вычислить синус  введенного числа и поместить его в TextBox1. Стерев то число, которое я ввел. Как это организовать в Visual Studio?
язык написания C#(си шарп)

Comment: А язык какой?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хм. В обработчике нажатия на кнопку пишете примерно следующий код:

```
TextBox1.Text = Math.Sin(Convert.ToDouble(TextBox1.Text));
```